# Complex Object related Question

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the correct way to construct Complex Object if part of Complex Object is expressed as Adjective and Noun.
I am aware of the Complex Object rule of this kind (I saw her come/ I saw her coming) but confused with the following sentences.

Are they constructed correctly? if not, please advise what grammar says on that.

a)  Dan saw the owner of the house be in the garden.                      Verb

b)  I saw him be polite.                                                  Adjective

c)  I saw it be a bird outside the window.                                Noun

Thank you!!!

Comment: What do you mean by 'complex object'? In your example "I saw her come/coming", the direct object is just "her", not "her come/coming". The clause "come/coming" is complement of "saw", but not part of the direct object.

Comment: BIllJ, i might be mistaken but that is a typical example of what i have always thougth to be "Complex Object".  At least that term is widely used  in Russian speaking literature.If i am wrong in naming the gramamtical phenomenon, could you please tell me if the sentences below are correct. Thank you!

Comment: It might help to use different examples. The main thing that's confusing about the ones given is not word order but the use of "saw" with "to be"; it's philosophically hard to witness a state of being. If you said "I saw the bird feeding outside the window," or even "I saw the bird being fed outside the window," there would be nothing amiss. One could even somewhat understand "I saw him be polite," or even better "be rude," because in this case we're implying actions that could be imagined, rather than static state-of-being.

Comment: @IRINA Gramatically, there is nothing 'complex' about it (see my first comment) In fact, English does not have such a term. The a) and c) sentences are ungrammatical, and b) is grammatical but unlikely

Comment: BillJ, thank you very much! Could me, please, direct me to the rule, explanation of why the a) and b) are incorrect. I was searching in Pullum, but failed to find any similar example. it asuredly sounds wrong, but i took "i saw him come" or "i saw he awarded" as reference and came up with wrong sentences. Thank you once again! Have a good day!